# How to use Multiple camera with an Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4?

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I have RPI CM4 and I would like to use 2 cameras on his board. I have noticed that the RPI CM4 have 2 CSI port camera but I can't found any informations on how to select the right camera on the right CSI port camera.

Thank you.

Comment: have you visited the rasp pi forums yet??? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/

Comment: Yes I have already look the rpi forums. (And I found nothing to drive multiple camera with picamera lib)